# reverseCase along with swap Integer in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, foreach, swap, chararray

I am trying to write an effective code to reverse Case in kotlin .

*HeLLo 5worLD6*  -> **hEllO 6WORld5**
5 and 6 are swap as they have equal difference

Initially I am trying to swap digit's but forEachIndex doesn't change in my existing list . Why?

```
val uniqueWords = str.split(" ").map { it.toCharArray() }
    uniqueWords.forEachIndexed { index, chars ->
        chars.forEachIndexed { charIndex, c ->
            val endIndex = chars.lastIndex - charIndex
            if(c.isDigit() && chars[endIndex].isDigit()){
                chars[charIndex] = chars[endIndex]
                chars[endIndex] = c
            }
        }
    }
```

val mVal = uniqueWords // but it doesn't swap integers

Comment: It's not clear what logic you want to follow for whether two characters should be swapped. Your `endIndex` is the distance between each character and the end which means it points to the character that is the same distance from the center of the string. 5 and 6 are clearly not the same distance from the center of the string in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
chars.forEachIndexed { charIndex, c ->
    val endIndex = chars.lastIndex - charIndex
```

You're iterating over each char/index of each word, and `endIndex` is a mirror offset right? As `charIndex` moves from the start to the end, `endIndex` moves from the end to the start.

So on the first iteration, *charIndex = 0* and *endIndex = (6 - 0) = 6*. Those indices both have digits, so they swap. The array now holds `6WORld5`

On the last iteration, *charIndex = 6* and *endIndex = (6 - 6) = 0*. Those indices both have digits, so they swap (again). The array is back to `5WORld6`

Every swap is gonna happen twice, because each pair of indices will be checked twice - once with `charIndex` pointing at the lower index, and once with `endIndex` pointing at it. If you visualise what you want to happen, it's probably more like the two ends moving towards the middle, and stopping there, right?